# How to submit multiple transaction to a blockchain block?

Tags: blockchain

How do I submit multiple transactions to a block using the REST API?

All the examples just submit or update a single transaction in a block.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: Nearly same question, see the following link
[http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/populus-how-to-have-multiple-transactions-in-a-single-block](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/populus-how-to-have-multiple-transactions-in-a-single-block)

Answer (score 0):

In each blockchain branch there can only be one block at every height as every block references their ancestor.

If a block includes a transaction that was already confirmed by one of their ancestors, the block is invalid. Invalid blocks are rejected by the nodes in the network. Therefore, one chain branch can never confirm the same transaction more than once.

If there are two blocks at the same height in the blockchain confirming the same transaction, that's fine. They are already competing as only one of them can be part of the longest chain anyway. The other will become stale as the majority chain moves forward.

You can learn more about Blockchain and implementing your own Blockchain @ [IBM Blockchain 101: A quick-start developer guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-101-quick-start-guide-for-developers-bluemix-trs/index.html)